# Same dojo.data-store for dijit.tree and dojox.grid

Tags: dojox.grid, dojo

I want to implement a kind of file-browser, where the user can navigate using the folder-tree, and see the folder-content in a grid.

I want to use the same data-store for both widgets, but can't see how to achive this - the tree needs items with e.g. a children-attribute, the grid only needs those children.
because ther may be a huge dataset, I'm planning to use the jsonreststore.

Answer (score 0):

i was trying with this, and got one solution like this, Please note that the grid and tree are using the **same store.**. Here the catch is if folder has id of fld1 then all the files under that folder should have id pattern like "fld1f1","fld1f2".

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html dir="ltr">

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html { font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif; font-size:90%; }
    </style>
    <script src="djlib/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="djlib/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="djlib/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css"/>
</head>
<body class=" claro ">
    <div id="treeOne"></div>
    <div id="gridHolder" style="height:500px"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    s =[];
    dojo.require("dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel");
    dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
    dojo.require("dijit.Tree");     
    dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");


    dojo.addOnLoad(function(){          
        baseStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
            data:{
                identifier: 'id',
                label: 'name',
                items: [                        

                    {id:'fld1',name:'folder 1', type:"folder", files:[{_reference:'fld1f1'},{_reference:'fld1f2'}]},
                    {id:'fld1f1',name:'file 1 of folder 1', type:"file", size:'1KB', dateLstMod:'15/15/2001'},
                    {id:'fld1f2',name:'file 2 of folder 1', size:'1KB', type:"file", dateLstMod:'15/15/2001'},
                    {id:'fld2',name:'folder 2', type:"folder", files:[{_reference:'fld2f1'},{_reference:'fld2f2'}]},
                    {id:'fld2f1',name:'file 1 of folder 2', size:'1KB', type:"file", dateLstMod:'15/15/2001'},
                    {id:'fld2f2',name:'file 2 of folder 2', size:'1KB', type:"file",dateLstMod:'15/15/2001'},
                    {id:'fld3',name:'folder 3', type:"folder"}
                ]
            }
        });     

        treeModel = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({
            store: baseStore,
            query:{
                type:'folder'
            },
            rootId: "root",
            rootLabel: "List of folders on this drive",
            childrenAttrs:['files']
        })

        t = new dijit.Tree({
            model: treeModel                
        },"treeOne")

        dojo.connect(t,'onClick', function(item, node, evt){                
            if(node.isExpandable){
                updateGrid(baseStore.getValues(item,"id"));                 
            }
        })          
        function updateGrid(folderId){              
            grid.filter({
                type:'file' , id:folderId+'*'
            },true);
        }                   
        var gridStr = [{
            cells:[
                [
                    { field: "name", name: "File Name", width: 'auto' },
                    { field: "size", name: "Size", width: 'auto'},
                    { field: "dateLstMod", name: "Date Last Modified", width: 'auto'}                           
                ]
            ]
        }]          
        grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
            store:baseStore,                
            structure: gridStr,             
            noDataMessage:"NO DATA"
        }, 'gridHolder');           
        grid.startup();
        grid.filter({
                type:'filee'
        },true);
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this link has the answer, you don't point the grid at the store, you create the grid and add items by iterating across the relevant children in the store

http://groups.google.com/group/dojo-interest/browse_thread/thread/af7265b19edeeb0/9fee8b5498746dd8